# Option "useFindAndModify" is not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to my database using mongoose and in my console is displaying ' option usefindandmodify is not supproted '. I'm using mongoose 6.0.0

this is my code

```
  mongoose.connect(constants.CONNECTION_URL,
     { useNewUrlParser: true,
       useUnifiedTopology: true, 
       useFindAndModify: false 
     })
.then(() => app.listen(constants.PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port ${constants.PORT}`)))
.catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

can someone suggest me how can I get rid of that? is written with white if matters neither green nor red, white.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with Mongoose version 6, you **should not** specify that as an option. It will be handled automatically.

This [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10518) is explained [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options).

> `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, `useFindAndModify`, and `useCreateIndex` are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, and `useCreateIndex` are true, and `useFindAndModify` is false. Please remove these options from your code.

Answer (score 0):

i got this error too ,  so i fixed that like this
i guess `useNewUrlParser`, `useUnifiedTopology`, `useFindAndModify` are no longer available

```
mongoose.connect(constants.CONNECTION_URL).then(() => app.listen(constants.PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port ${constants.PORT}`)))
.catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL) .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(Server running on port ${PORT})) ).catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

Comment: mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL)
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I've edited your answer and placed the code in your comment into the actual post _ In future please don't add additions in comments but click the 'Edit' button instead

Answer (score 0):

New version of Mongoose don't support `useFindAndModify`, you don't have to write it in your code, Mongoose by default takes `useFindAndModify` as false.

just remove `useFindAndModify` from your code.