# Error: `useFindAndModify` is an invalid option

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am new to MERN stack and I am following MERN stack tutorial on YouTube. I got an **error** on Mongoose.

```
Error: `useFindAndModify` is an invalid option
```

I couldn't find any solution to that.

```js
    import express from "express";
    import bodyParser from "body-parser";
    import mongoose from "mongoose";
    import cors from "cors";


    const app = express();
    app.use(bedyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

    app.use(cors());

    const CONNECTION_URL =
    "mongodb+srv://myratcharyyev:<password>@clustero.mn9xi.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    mongoose
    .connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    // useCreateIndex: true
    })
    .then(( =>
    app.listen (PORT, () => console.log("Server running on port: ${PORT}'))
    )
    .catch((error) => console.log(error message));
    mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Option "useFindAndModify" is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915722/option-usefindandmodify-is-not-supported)

Comment: no, I have tried that too, but couldn't help

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you using?

Answer (score 39):

It's a deprecated now.
// No longer necessary:

```
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
  useNewUrlParser: true, // <-- no longer necessary
  useUnifiedTopology: true // <-- no longer necessary
});
```

use this line of code

```
mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL).then(()=>{console.log('...')})
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#mongoose-connect-returns-a-promise

Answer (score 10):

You are explicitly setting `useFindAndModify` with `.set()`. Remove the line below:

```
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
```