# Unable to connect to my database from my node js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been trying to connect my application to my database, but it has not been possible. I've tried this below, and it still did not recognize my models

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

// Database Name
const dbName = 'KaydeeAcedemy';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    client.close();
});
```

I've also tried using this connection string, yet no headway.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
    // perform actions on the collection object
    client.close();
  });
```

when I try to add a new user from my application, i get this error as a result of the database.

```
Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

the mongodb url looks like this:

```
MONGODB_URL = mongodb+srv://Kaydeeacademy:**************@cluster0.ehclf.mongodb.net/KaydeeAcademy?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I don't know if I missed something in the connection string or somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test/compare out some of my code (working)

```
// have you called in the dot.env file?
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


// don't include the "useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true" see answer below:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915722/option-usefindandmodify-is-not-supported


// make sure there are no spaces in the dot.env file
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => console.log("db connected!"))
  .catch(err => console.error("db connection failed ", err))
```